# Angular 2 get .length but count only specific data in the html or ts component

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, single-page-application

Given the script below below:

```
//just a dummy data source for our list
import { healthModel } from './healthModel';

export const healthListAll: healthModel[] =
[
    {
      id: 1,
      Name: 'Asparagus',
      healthGroup: 'Vegetable',
      isAvail: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      Name: 'Banana',
      healthGroup: 'Fruit',
      isAvail: 0
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      Name: 'Pomegranate',
      healthGroup: 'Fruit',
      isAvail: 1
    }, 
    {
      id: 2,
      Name: 'Artichoke',
      healthGroup: 'Vegetable',
      isAvail: 0
    }
]
```

on the `ts` component I can do `healthList = healthListAll;`

So I can get the total count on the `html` component via 
`{{healthList.length}}`

However, is there a way for me to only get the length of items where
`isAvail = 0` or by `healthGroup`? can I do it on html component so it's clean?
or could it be only done on the ts component?

Apologies. Quite new to angular.

Comment: If you want to use a filter directly on your template you need to create a Pipe and that's all. Search for the documentation of custom pipes on angular.io . Basically the pipe will do the filter and the template will render only the result of the pipe

Comment: @CryingFreeman understood, thanks I found the documentation here as well (https://angular.io/api/core/Pipe). I may have to look at a tutorial for this one however..

Comment: You can create a Pipe as much as flexible as you want, and it needs to be testable too

Comment: here an example https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-pipes-example    . the filter is just Javascript , the pipe is the magic of angular

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing this out. Will focus on solutions with pipes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get get the length of items where `isAvail = 0` or by `healthGroup` you have to do it in your ts

```
 var length=this.healthListAll.filter(x=>x.isAvil==0).length
    var length=this.healthListAll.filter(x=>x.healthGroup=='Fruit').length
```

Comment: I see, what does `x` in both syntaxes stand for?

Comment: x would be each element in the array.

Answer (score 1):

The template is not capable to do that so you can only apply filter, sort, etc... logic in your component then you can binding the data to the template using interpolation.

Hope it help.